# Can an xbox 360 controller be used on PC with a standard wireless adapter?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers

I have bought an Xbox 360 wireless controller and I want to use it on pc, but unfortunately, I cant find the Xbox 360 wireless receiver. Is it possible to use a normal wireless adapter for Xbox 360 controller?

Comment: It'd be nice if you were a bit more specific what you mean by "normal" wireless adapter. The exact model, for instance.

Comment: I'm going to disagree on the dupe.  This is a different enough problem from "How do I use a wireless 360 controller on PC?" to remain open IMHO.

Comment: What exactly is a normal wireless adapter? WiFi card? I don't get what the reference is except for the dongle made for PC.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft uses a proprietary version of Bluetooth for the wireless Xbox 360 controllers, so any wireless card or dongle you have simply won't see the controller. USB will only charge the controller, there is no data exchange at all on it. You will need to buy the $20 wireless adapter for PC to use a wireless Xbox 360 controller on your computer.

You may also need to install additional drivers depending on your OS and OS version.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use the supplied Microsoft Adapter. <strike>Alternatively you can connect via the Play and Charge Cable (however it will not be wireless).</strike> This is incorrect as per the comments below.

However any Microsoft Adapter should work (they are not paired to each other) and can be found reasonably online.

Comment: This is incorrect.  [The charge and play kit is not sufficient by itself to use the controller on PC.](http://superuser.com/a/253970/17529)

Comment: I stand corrected, I updated the answer to reflect this.